# Rails Updating Data in one Model from another Model's Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, rails-models

I have a User model that has billing_id. I have Order model that runs transactions with a payment gateway which returns a billing id I'd like to save into the billing_id column on the User model. I think I am getting the basics of MVC architecture mixed up.

I am under the impression that UsersController and OrdersController update data of their respective tables. Does that mean that if I have something returned from OrdersController such as a billing id, there is no other way of saving that billing id into a billing_id column in User model? Thanks and sorry if this is extremely rudimentary. :)

Also, I thought a possible solution might be to somehow pass in the return value via ApplicationsController into UsersController to save into User table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user orders table should have an instance of user_id, as a user can have multiple orders.

You can do this by creating a migration:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_orders order_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Your models will then look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You need a link between the two (order_id) otherwise they would have no knowledge of each other.  This is known as a foreign key.

When things are set up this way, you can get the users by doing:

```
User.find(1).orders
```

And you can find the user information from an order by doing:

```
Orders.find(1).user
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT:

```
Orders.find(ORDER_ID).user.update_attributes(:billing_id => BILLING_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks Gazler. I already set it up this way. Currently, I am concerned with how I might be able take a return value of a new order creation and save into the User table from OrdersController. Thanks for the input

Comment: Why would you need to save this value to the user?  Is it not associated to the Order?  Could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes. billingID is returned when creditcard number is saved in payment gateways database. I wanted to have billingID column in User table and save it there instead of in a Order table because billingID is returned only when it's a new credit card being saved.

Comment: Thank you very much. So is it possible to update an attribute of User table from OrdersController? I think it's a fundamental MVC issue that I haven't been able to grasp well.

Comment: I assume in your OrdersController you have an order variable.  So replace Orders.find(ORDER_ID) with @order.

Comment: I am sorry, but if I do update_attributes from OrdersController, doesn't it only relate to attributes of the Order model? As in if I ran Orders.find(ORDER_ID).user.update_attributes(:billing_id => BILLING_ID) it'd be looking for :billing_id in Order table.

Comment: No.  Orders.find(ORDER_ID).user retrieved the user object that the order belongs to.