# Rails - Don't know how to save data from a form into another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Movie model and an Actor model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :genre
has_many :reviews 
has_many :actors

end



class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :movies

end
```

These are the attributes for each model:

```
create_table "actors", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.text     "bio"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "movie_id"
end

create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.integer  "duration"
t.date     "release_date"
t.text     "plot"
t.string   "director"
t.text     "cast"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end
```

When a user fills out the form to create a new movie, I want the input from the 'cast' field to save to the Actor model. What action(s) would I need in my controller and what would I need to do in my form?

I've looked at and tried the following and I'm still stuck:

[Rails Updating Data in one Model from another Model's Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587398/rails-updating-data-in-one-model-from-another-models-controller)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

[How can I update and save one model from another in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167482/how-can-i-update-and-save-one-model-from-another-in-rails)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a nested form. You'll need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors` to the movie model, then build a subform within the form... Better explanation here:

http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/advanced-forms

Scroll down to "Nested Forms".